# Create a measure which divide two KPIs based on different periods

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculation, measure

I have a table as presented below.

I would like to calculate KPI (#Handled/#Total Offered) and present it using CREATION YEAR MONTH NUMBER on chart but when I am trying to calculate it, it changes to 100% as #handled = #total offered.

**#Total Offered** = DISTINCTCOUNT(TABLE[REFERENCE_NUMBER])

**#Handled** = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(TABLE1[REFERENCE_NUMBER];TABLE1[IS_CASE_CLOSED])=1))

**#Total Offered** is presented by CREATION_YEAR_MONTH_NUMBER

**#Handled** is presented by CURRENT_CASE_STAGE_YEAR_MONTH_NUMBER

I would like to do it as presented below:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to solve the case?

Comment: Are you using a separate date table or are you working with one flat table?

Comment: Is there possibilities of having duplicate reference number?

Comment: It's one flat table. No, there is no possibility to duplicate reference number.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below 2 **Measure**? If your coulmn **is_case_handled** contain always 0 and 1 properly, these simple below measures should work for you.

```
total_offered = count(your_table_name[is_case_closed])
```

```
total_handled = sum((your_table_name[is_case_closed]))
```